# How to add Firebase SDK to JAVA application?

Tags: java, eclipse, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to add Firebase admin SDK to my Java app following the steps at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart. There are two subsections: "Using Gradle" and "Using Maven". But what if I use Eclipse for Windows? What entries should I add to Java Build Path?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question, but your use of Eclipse is not an _alternative_ to using Maven or Gradle. Maven and Gradle are tools to help manage project dependencies and to help manage the project build. So, instead, you can use either of these tools with most commonly used IDEs (Eclipse, Intellij, Netbeans...).For example, if you are using Eclipse, you can choose to create a new Java Maven project (plenty of tutorials). This will give you a "starter" POM file. You will then add the dependency mentioned in the "quickstart" link to that POM file. That's it. Build dependency handled!

Comment: I suppose you're right, thank you. But does it mean that it's impossible (or too difficult) to add Firebase SDK without Maven?

Comment: You can download the firebase admin jar manually, e.g from the [Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/6.12.2), and then add it to your project manually, in the same way that you would add any other JAR to your project. But then you may also have to manually download any JARs which are dependencies of the firebase JAR (if there are any)... and then any dependencies of those JARs... and so on. Doing this, you are basically doing by hand what Maven (or Gradle) does for you automatically - and with no repeatable configuration. But you can do it.